# how to open .frm and .myd files on mac

Tags: mysql

I want to open .frm and .myd files on macosx. Can anyone please suggest me anything. I was trying to open it with Mysql workbench but didn't get any success.

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install the MySQL database engine, place them in the appropriate directory, start the server, and connect to it.

Comment: Mysql engine and server is running on my machine. Can you please elaborate how could I see the content of these files.

Comment: Place them in the appropriate directory, start the server, and connect to it.

Comment: I placed them /usr/local/mysql/data/dbname/. and restart the server but still it is not working. Can you please explain it more.

Comment: "The appropriate directory" is located next to all the existing databases. Try under /var/lib or the like.